# unable to execute SQL Statement from Putty

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to Connect Oracle DB and execute SQL statement from Putty rather than TOAD.
I have been able to connect via Putty but sql query not giving answers.
Here are the results blow:

```
Enter user-name: mkandoi
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options


Session altered.

mkandoi@LCTIDFT> select count(*) from iordl
  2
```

Every time when I run a query the cursor comes to the next line. where I can write a any thing, but no result is appearing.

Comment: Every SQL statement must be ended with a `;`

Comment: sometime we don't need semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Please add semicolon at the end of query